# Using OpenCV on windows and Clion

Tags: c++, opencv, cmake, mingw, clion

So I'm trying to use OpenCV on windows (my ubunut is broken) and I can't configure my Clion to compile my openCV code.
first; i'm completely new to OpenCV so this question might be an easy one but I did all I could to find the problem to no avail.
I used MinGW and Clion and my codes run with no problem if I don't use OpenCv which indicates there's no problem with MinGW installation. 
I downloaded OpenCv files and extracted them, then added them to System path. 
after that I configured my Cmakelists.txt (my first time modifying it, so I was an amateur) like [this](https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/doc/tutorials/introduction/linux_gcc_cmake/linux_gcc_cmake.html).
After that I got this error:

> Error:By not providing "FindOpenCV.cmake" in CMAKE_MODULE_PATH this
>   project has asked CMake to find a package configuration file provided
>   by "OpenCV", but CMake did not find one. Could not find a package
>   configuration file provided by "OpenCV" with any of the following
>   names: OpenCVConfig.cmake opencv-config.cmake Add the installation
>   prefix of "OpenCV" to CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH or set "OpenCV_DIR" to a
>   directory containing one of the above files. If "OpenCV" provides a
>   separate development package or SDK, be sure it has been installed.

I know I'm doing something wrong or missing a step but I can't figure out why. is there any guide or tutorial for my scenario or can anyone point me towards a correct direction?
thanks in advance and any help appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to make those errors go away with changing my 
**CMakeLists.txt** to:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.5)

project(something)

set(OpenCV_DIR "E:/Programs/programming/opencv/build2") find_package( OpenCV REQUIRED )

set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -std=c++11")

set(SOURCE_FILES main.cpp) add_executable(something ${SOURCE_FILES})

add_executable( {SOURCE_FILES} DisplayImage ) target_link_libraries( ${OpenCV_LIBS} DisplayImage )
```

and building the libraries on my own by minGW and Cmake.